# auto refresh not working webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Auto refresh is not working with webpack-dev-server, However its compile the file and I have to manual refresh. I have tried difference config suggested by the people but none of them work.

**dev-server.js**

```
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var compiler = webpack(config);
var server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler,{
  inline: true,
  hot: true,
  filename: config.output.filename,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats:{
    colors: true
  }
})


server.listen(8080,'localhost', function () {

})
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports ={
  entry : ['./src/index.js'],
  module:{
    loaders:[{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }
    ]
  },
  output:{
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    publicPath:'/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-training",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack",
    "dev": "node dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

When using `webpack-dev-server` directly then it is working fine.

```
"serve": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
```